# Why doesn't Git remove some files when I switch a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have had this happen to me often. I am working on a master branch and I need to test a plugin, so I create a new branch and check it out. I download the plugin into the project directory and test it out. Then I switch back to the master branch and delete the branch I had created.

What ends up happening is the files of the plugin remain in the project directory. I'm wondering if this is normal behavior. What do I have to do in order to have a seamless switch between branches?

Comment: git will not remove untracked files from your working copy, so unless you added the files of the plugin and created a commit on the new branch git will not do anything to your plugin files

Comment: @knittl: *that* is the answer. Might as well post it. (Along with a mention of `git clean`, perhaps.)

Comment: A more explaining answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900249/why-are-folders-left-in-my-local-git-working-directory-after-commit-and-checkout

Answer (score 13, accepted):

git will not remove untracked files from your working copy, so unless you added the files of the plugin and created a commit on the new branch git will not do anything to your plugin files.

if you want to remove untracked file from your working tree, use [`git clean`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-clean.html) – be careful, it will remove any untracked file from disk and there's no way to recover from that (without using undelete software)

Comment: The potential danger of `git clean`, of course, is why it won't even do anything unless you pass it the `-f` option. (Possibly helpful for this case - you can use it on specific paths.)

Comment: why "git will not remove untracked files from your working copy"? will my next `git add` add those untracked files from different branch?

Comment: @joetsuihk: untracked files in the working directory do not belong to any branch, they belong to the working directory. if you `git add` untracked files, they will be included in the next commit

Comment: @knittl `git add .` do not add those files from my experience, not even listed as "untracked", why? But it has a potential to mess up different branches files if branches contains different files?

Comment: @joetsuihk: I don't understand what you are trying to say … `git add .` will add all files contained in the current directory and all it's subdirectories, unless they match a rule from a `.gitignore` file. And it will **never** mess up branches. Branches are only pointers to a commit object – which in turn points to it's ancestor commit(s) – and those commit objects are set in stone and not touched by git (except for `rebase`, `filter-branch` and `commit --amend`). Maybe we should move this discussion to [chat]?

Comment: @knittl first time use chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4903/why-git-will-not-remove-untracked-files-from-your-working-copy

Comment: Your link to git clean is stale.

Try:  http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/16/cleaning-up-untracked-files.html

or: http://man.cx/git-clean

Comment: @AmielMartin: yeah, … I guess all git links to kernel.org are stale, since the security breach last fall.

Answer (score 2):

If you are switching back and forth between branches where the directory structures are different, and you find that there are some artifacts left over, you might need to run:

```
git clean -df
```

This will "delete" "force". You will loose ALL untracked files, I think this might be one step away from:

```
git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 1):

try checkout -f

see git --help checkout:

Proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. 
This is used to throw away local changes.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP's experiencing. The checkout proceeds, but leaves some files there.