# Git- Switched to a new branch but files from other branch still exists Drupal

Tags: git, branch, working-directory

I cloned a git repo from the server, switched to a branch A that is in origin. Then I installed a bunch of contrib modules committed them to a new local branch B. Now I wanted to work on a clean version of the origin branch A. So I created another new local branch C from the origin repo. 
Now when I try to install a similar contrib module in my fresh local branch C that I committed in branch B, I see the module files already exist.

**Shouldn't switching branches allow me to work on a clean fresh copy?**

Also when I switch branches back to the origin branch A, I still see the modules I downloaded for branch b. Since this is the fresh checkout I suppose I should not see them but I do? I tried reading through the various git material but could not understand whats wrong with my current setup.

Any Clues?

**Update**
How I installed Contrib modules?
Drush dl which is how you download new modules in drupal. This just adds a new folder to your current folder structure and its related entry in your database

Created new local branches

```
git checkout -b mylocalbranch-B

git checkout A
git checkout -b mylocalbranch
```

Comment: 1. Then I installed a bunch of contrib modules committed them to a new local branch B
2. Now I wanted to work on a clean version of the origin branch A. So I created another new local branch C from the origin repo.

Can you specify the commands for both these?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "...switched to a branch A that is in origin"

Comment: Updated my question to answer those

Comment: git will not remove untracked files from your working copy. So if you did "clone, checkout B, installed plugins, checkout A, checkout B2" then you haven't added/commited any files so they are still untracked. So when you switch branches they are still there. You need to add them and commit them in a branch.

Comment: @Peter I committed them to my branch B but when I checkout branch C, I still see those files on my folder directory

Comment: And you check out C from A, i.e not from B? That sounds impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

[Why doesn't Git remove some files when I switch a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156648/why-doesnt-git-remove-some-files-when-i-switch-a-branch)

summary: the files are probably not tracked. Solution: switch to original branch, "git add [filesthatwerentaddedyet]" and then, when you change from branch again, I think it will remove the files.

Comment: I did look at the response to that question. Even though I switch branches via Git checkout I still see my oldfiles