# Why are folders left in my local git working directory after commit and checkout

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout

I have created a folder containing files in my local working git structure. I created a new branch with git checkout -b and used git add . and git commit -m "..." to add those files to my local branch. But, when I do git checkout master the folder I created and committed is still there. Why? I thought git commit would put the folder and its contents into my local branch, switching it out when I checkout master.

Comment: As a note of terminology: `git checkout -b <name>` creates a new "branch", not a new "repo". The repo refers to the whole git directory.

Comment: Git normally deletes empty folders ... are there perhaps any hidden files?

Comment: No, there are no hidden files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add previously untracked files to a new branch, and then you checkout another branch that doesn't currently track those files, it won't remove them from your working copy.

Here's an example—let's say I'm currently on a clean branch named `old_branch`, and I checkout a new branch named `new_branch`:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
```

Then, I create a new file named `test.txt` in this branch and add it to the repo:

```
touch test.txt  # creates a new file named test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m "Added test.txt"
```

The `test.txt` file is currently tracked by the `new_branch` branch. However, when I switch branches back to `old_branch`:

```
git checkout old_branch
```

Since `test.txt` is not tracked by `old_branch`, it leaves it in the working directory and doesn't overwrite it. This is expected behavior. If you do `git status` at this point, you'll notice that the `test.txt` file is currently untracked.

---

For completion's sake, if you need to clean your working copy of all untracked files, you can first do:

```
git clean -n
```

This will list all untracked files that will be removed. If you're satisfied with the list, you can them remove those files with:

```
git clean -f -d
```

*This is a destructive command*, especially since it deletes files that are not tracked by the current branch. (It won't delete them from branches that do track those files though.)

Comment: So what is different between that and when I do git push after add and commit? Why are the tracked files being removed or cleaned if they don't exist in the old_branch branch?

Comment: `git push` only pushes your current branch upstream, aka to your remote branch. It's not entirely relevant to the problem you describe of the untracked files not being removed when you switch branches.

Comment: And to your other question—if a file is tracked by both the `new_branch` and the `old_branch`, it will be overwritten by each branch when I check them out. On the other hand, if a file is tracked by one branch and not the other, switching branches will not change the file because the other branch isn't looking for it. As such, the `git clean` command can be used to remove files from your local machine that _are not being tracked by the current branch_.

Comment: I get all of that. What I'm asking is why a file which is tracked by the current branch does not disappear when I checkout a branch which does not have it? This in a scenario where I have not pushed to remote but have done an add and commit before the checkout.